# DatagridView cell click event in visual c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am learning `Windows Visual C#` so I am new to this. I have this code for the cell click event for my DataGridView

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
      con.  ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
      txtname.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
      txtlname.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    }
```

> **The question is:**  Even how many times I click my DataGridView it's not firing my breakpoint. How to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure you are clicking on your cells in the grid? Because your code seems fine.

Comment: did you add event handler ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553231.aspx it might be a bit easier to try it in VB.Net until you get used to event handlers

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid yes I am sure. After I click my DataGridView I want the data to be display in textboxes

Comment: Check your form designer and confirm that you got this  `this.dataGridView1.CellClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellClick);`.

Comment: @Berkay I don't see anything like that in my designer

Comment: @KiRa So, your event won't be fired until, select datagridview-> F4-> Lightining Icon -> Double click to, CellClick's textbox.

Comment: @Berkay wait I will follow what you have said.

Comment: @Berkay its working now `Select DGV > F4 > Lightning Icon > CellClick > select the event`

Comment: @KiRa Just adding images to explain better :) Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this,

You can reach properties by right clicking or pressing F4 after selecting `datagridview`.

[image]

After press lightining icon and double click to event that you like to handle.

[image]

Finally you will see this,

[image]

Hope helps,